# Trouble sending a batch create entity request in dialogflow

Tags: python-3.x, dialogflow-es

I have defined the following function. The purpose is to make batch create entity request with dialogflow client. I am using this method after sending many individual tests did not scale well.

The problem seems to be the line that defines EntityType. Seems like "entityType" is not valid but that is what is in the dialogflow v2 documentation which is the current version I am using.

Any ideas on what the issue is?

```
def create_batch_entity_types(self):
    client = self.get_entity_client()
    print(DialogFlowClient.batch_list)

    EntityType = {
        "entityTypes": DialogFlowClient.batch_list
    }

    response = client.batch_update_entity_types(parent=AGENT_PATH, entity_type_batch_inline=EntityType)

    def callback(operation_future):
        # Handle result.
        result = operation_future.result()
        print(result)

    response.add_done_callback(callback)
```

After running the function I received this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "df_client.py", line 540, in <module>
    create_entity_types_from_database()
  File "df_client.py", line 426, in create_entity_types_from_database
    df.create_batch_entity_types()
  File "/Users/andrewflorial/Documents/PROJECTS/curlbot/dialogflow/dialogflow_accessor.py", line 99, in create_batch_entity_types
    response = client.batch_update_entity_types(parent=AGENT_PATH, entity_type_batch_inline=EntityType)
  File "/Users/andrewflorial/Documents/PROJECTS/curlbot/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dialogflow_v2/gapic/entity_types_client.py", line 767, in batch_update_entity_types
    update_mask=update_mask,
ValueError: Protocol message EntityTypeBatch has no "entityTypes" field.
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument for `entity_type_batch_inline` must have the same form as `EntityTypeBatch`.

Look how that type looks like: https://dialogflow-python-client-v2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gapic/v2/types.html#dialogflow_v2.types.EntityTypeBatch

It has to have `entity_types` field, not `entityTypes`.